# Why is it such an effort to setup code coverage in TeamCity?

Tags: 64-bit, teamcity, code-coverage, partcover

I'm using Teamcity 6.0 and want to add code coverage to our NUnit tests.

PartCover has been a massive issue due to it not running on x64 server and so now I have to go and git it and build it myself :(

Also, jetBrains, if you know the xslt is broken, make it easier for me to fix it.

Does anyone else have PartCover working?. Maybe this might help :
http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/23/using-teamcity-with-partcover-4/

Comment: Can someone give me access to a x64 signed stable build of PartCover please?

Comment: There is now a new code coverage tool (beta) called [OpenCover][1] it has 32 and 64 bit support


  [1]: https://github.com/sawilde/opencover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bother! Just install dotCover. It just works!

Comment: Really!?! The option is there but I think you need to install the command part?!

Comment: No. It's integrated. See http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/12/coverage-with-dotcover-teamcity-mstest-nunit-or-mspec/